# Agreed Upon Between - Is It a Correct Phrase

Tags: american-english

Is "agreed upon between [two parties]" a correct way to say that there were two parties that agreed upon something (that is, there was an agreement **between** them)?

"Agreed upon **by**" sounds more natural to me, but then, the "negotiation element" seems to be lost, doesn't it?

Comment: You could just go with _agreed between [two parties]_.

Answer (score 1):

You have an elegant solution in your question: the active voice phrasing "the two parties agreed upon [the settlement agreement].” Unless you have a compelling reason to phrase it passively, you already have a winning phrase!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a compelling reason - I cannot change the subject of the sentence. But "agreed between" is great, thanks!